# Include path ignored

Tags: php, include-path, ini-set, set-include-path

I have the following code (simplified) to add a path to my include paths (to temporarily fix an website with old code).

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/foo/bar');
```

I have a settings file `/foo/settings/settings.inc.php`

Now when I have set the include path and I am in a file `/foo/bar/members.php` I want to include the settings file. So what the code does is:

```
include '../settings/settings.inc.php'
```

I would think that it would get that file now. But it doesn't. When I put the full path in the include it does work. eg: `/foo/settings/settings.inc.php` but there are a lot of files. And I thought that this would be a work around for that so I don't have to replace every file manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say [you can't do that](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> Files are included based on the file path given or, **if none is
> given**, the include_path specified. [...]
>
> **If a path is defined** — whether absolute (starting with a drive letter
> or \ on Windows, or / on Unix/Linux systems) or relative to the
> current directory (starting with . or ..) — **the include_path will be
> ignored** altogether.

Comment: So as soon as there is something of a path (e.g `../file.php` or `/foo/file.php` it completely ignores the include path? And it only uses the include path if I give `file.php` only? Hmm. Well, than all I can do is change a lot of files.

Comment: I have no idea of what you're trying to accomplish but... Why is batch search and replace unfeasible? It's a two minute task with any decent editor?

Comment: And that is the route I went.

Comment: Whatever you're doing... I've heavily used the [auto_prepend_file](http://php.net/auto_prepend_file) directive to make really ugly and old sites work in modern servers. Good luck :)